# Why are function expressions so much slower than function declarations in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was surprised to run [these tests](http://jsperf.com/long-living-vs-anonymous-functions/5) and see that a singly-defined function statement was so much more performant than a singly-defined function expression:

[image: function tests]

I wasn't too surprised to see that the inner anonymous function was so slow, since I reasoned it was build on every iteration of the loop. But what is it about the difference between function expressions and statements which makes such a noticeable difference? And why is this difference so profound in Chrome?

[image]

Comment: What other Javascript engines have you tried? Your screenshot says Chrome, but that's only one data point. I just tried Firefox and it gives completely different performance numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433883/function-declaration-faster-than-function-expression

Comment: I ran it in Firefox and IE also, which shows more reasonable differences. So, it comes down to; what did Chrome do wrong?

Comment: Safari also shows very differently--the two which do not use IIFE are almost identical.

Comment: What you are calling a "function statement" is a function declaration, very few browsers implement function statements (Firefox is one), and there are none in the OP. The "anonymous function" is an immediately invoked function expression that must be parsed and evaluated each time, so of course it's slower than a declared function that is parsed only once.

Comment: Be careful of random tests on jsPerf. A test of [*4 different methods*](http://jsperf.com/function-creation-tests) of creating functions shows that they create functions that all run at about the same speed.

Comment: @Guffa yes, that's the question I'd like answered; what is it about Chrome's execution strategy that makes this so costly?

Comment: This has been closed because it's a duplicate, but I've altered it to be more specific and nominated it to be opened. Also note that the answers on the other question don't answer it.